# Canceling :active link css attribute

Tags: css

In the code as below, I want to disable "a:active" color style on (A) position.
Is there a good way for it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        a{ background-color: #000; }
        a.foo{ background-color: #0f0; }
        a.bar{ background-color: #00f; }
        a:active{ background-color: #f00; }
        /*
            (A) I want to cancel :active color here.
        */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">hoge</a>
    <a href="#" class="foo">foo</a>
    <a href="#" class="bar">bar</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel" or "disable"?

Comment: I want foo link is colored #0f0 when it's active,
and I want bar link is colored #00f when it's active.
Setting same colors again on (A) is a simple way, but it's not smart.

Comment: color or background-color?

Comment: Background-color. It's one sample of styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove property, so you can only overwrite it.

```
a.foo, a.foo:active{ background-color: #0f0; }
a.bar, a.bar:active{ background-color: #00f; }
```

Comment: You can effectively 'remove' a property by re-setting its value to the default, often this is `inherit` or `auto` (depending on the property. Always consult the CSS specification).

Comment: Thanks! I'm sad there's no smart way for removing, but I understand. I also try to use 'default', 'inherit' and 'auto' keywords in some cases.

Comment: @Dai, the default is browser-dependent. (Default, `inherit`, and `auto` are three different things.)

Comment: The general statement in the answer is correct, but the sample code does not address the question asked at all. The question was about color, not background color.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a mistake and I repaired it now. The sample indicates about "background-color" style, not "color" style.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        a{ color: #000; }
        a.foo{ background-color: #0f0; }
        a.bar{ background-color: #00f; }
        a.foo:active, a.bar:active{ background-color: #f00; }
        /*
            (A) I want to cancel :active color here.
        */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">hoge</a>
    <a href="#" class="foo">foo</a>
    <a href="#" class="bar">bar</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it's not my aim.
I hope a behavior as if "a:active" line would been removed.

Comment: If that's the case, you'll need to use JavaScript to change it dynamically, or simply restate the style for a:active, those are your only options.